# How to "Unlock Jenkins"?

Tags: jenkins

I am installing Jenkins 2 on windows,after installing,a page is opened,URL is:
http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F

**content of the page is like this:**
[image]

**Question:**
How to "Unlock Jenkins"?

Comment: There is a link on the page that tells you where to find the log, and the token is in the log.

Comment: @warmoverflow The content of the log is:```Running from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
Jenkins home directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")```It's not the answer.

Comment: In the mac, you can open this file and copy the password.  /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging

Comment: @sunshine is any of answers in this thread answering your question? you still didn't mark any answer.

Answer (score 32):

Starting from version 2.0 of Jenkins you may use

```
-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
```

to prevent this screen.

Accroding to documentation

> jenkins.install.runSetupWizard - Set to false to skip install wizard. Note that this leaves Jenkins unsecured by default.
>   Development-mode only: Set to true to not skip showing the setup wizard during Jenkins development.

More details about Jenkins properties can be found on this [Jenkins Wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties).

Comment: Also: `$JENKINS_ARGS` in `/etc/default/jenkins` is for Debian/Ubuntu ` /etc/sysconfig/jenkins` for CentOS/RedHat

Answer (score 9):

Check https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging to see where Jenkins is logging its files.

e.g. for Linux, use the command: `less /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`

And scroll down to the part: "Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created ... to proceed to installation:

[randompasswordhere] *<--- Copy and paste*

**Linux**

By default logs should be made available in `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`, unless customized in /etc/default/jenkins (for *.deb) or via /etc/sysconfig/jenkins (for */rpm)

**Windows**

By default logs should be at `%JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.out and %JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.err`, unless customized in %JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.xml

**Mac OS X**

Log files should be at `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`, unless customized in org.jenkins-ci.plist

Comment: I find the password in jenkins.err file in ec2 window server instance folder C:\Program Files\Jenkins

Answer (score 8):

1. open file: e:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword
2. copy content file: 47c5d4f760014e54a6bffc27bd95c077
3. paste in input: http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F

DONE

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Some of the above instructions seem to have gone out of date. As of the released version 2.0, creating the following file will cause Jenkins to skip the unlock screen:

```
${JENKINS_HOME}/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
```

This file must contain the string `2.0` **without any line terminators**. I'm not sure if this is required but Jenkins also sets the owner/group to be the same as the Jenkins server, so that's probably a good thing to mimic as well.

I did **not** need to create the `upgraded` or `.last_exec_version` files.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you were running jenkins.war manually with `java -jar jenkins.war`, then all logging information by default is output to standard out, just type the token to unlock jenkins2.0.
[image]

If you were not running jenkins with `java -jar jenkins.war`, then you can always follow this [Official Document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging) to find the correct log location.

Comment: Well, there is no token in the logs files. Just the text in @sunshine's comment above.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your terminal and type code below to find all the containers.

   docker container list -a
2. You will find **jenkinsci/blueocean** and/or **docker:dind** if not than

   `docker container run --name jenkins-docker --rm --detach ^
   --privileged --network jenkins --network-alias docker ^
   --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs ^
   --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client ^
   --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home ^
   --volume "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%":/home ^
   docker:dind`

   ```
            and
   ```

   `docker container run --name jenkins-blueocean --rm --detach ^
   --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 ^
   --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 ^
   --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home ^
   --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro ^
   --volume "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%":/home ^
   --publish 8080:8080 --publish 50000:50000 jenkinsci/blueocean`
3. run command

   docker run jenkinsci/blueocean
                 or
   docker run docker:dind
4. Copy and Paste the secret key.

Answer (score 2):

One method to prevent the installation wizard is to do the following in `$JENKINS_HOME`:

1. Create an empty file named `.last_exec_version`
2. Create a file named `upgraded`

   - If left empty, a banner will prompt you to "upgrade" to 2.0 (which just means install a bunch of new plugins like Pipeline)
   - If the contents of that file is `2.0`, you'll receive no banner and it will act like an regular old Jenkins install

Remember, this wizard is in place to prevent unauthorized access to Jenkins during setup. However, bypassing this wizard can be useful if, for example, you want to deploy automated installations of Jenkins with something like Ansible/Puppet/etc.

This was tested against Jenkins 2.0-beta-1 – so these instructions may not work in future beta or stable releases.

Answer (score 2):

In the mac use:

```
sudo more /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a lot of response to the question, most of them were actually solution to it but they solve the problem when jenkins is actually run as a standalone CI without Application container using the command:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

But when running on Tomcat as it is the case in this scenario, Jenkins logs are displayed on the catalina logs since the software is running on a container.
So you need to go to the logs folder:

```
C:\Program Files\tomcat_folder\Tomcat 8.5\logs\catalina.log
```

in my own case. Just scroll almost to the middle to look for a generated password which is essentially a token and copy and paste it to unlock jenkins.

I hope this fix your problem.

Comment: If you are not able to access the server log, or deleted it like me, look for the password at the location - `C:\Users\<username>\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword`. This is for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Open the terminal on your mac

Step 2: Concatenate or Paste

```
sudo cat **/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword**
```

Step 3: It will ask for password, type your mac password and enter

Step 4: A key would be generated.

Step 5: Copy and paste the security token in Jenkins

Step 6: Click continue

Answer (score 1):

I found the token in the following file in the installation dir:

```
<jenkins install dir>\users\admin\config.xml
```

and the element

```
<jenkins.install.SetupWizard_-AuthenticationKey>
<key> THE KEY </key>
</jenkins.install.SetupWizard_-AuthenticationKey>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might see it in the catalina.out. I installed Jenkins war in tomcat and I can see this in the catalina.out

Answer (score 1):

The below method does not work anymore on 2.42.2

Create an empty file named .last_exec_version
Create a file named upgraded
If left empty, a banner will prompt you to "upgrade" to 2.0 (which just means install a bunch of new plugins like Pipeline)
If the contents of that file is 2.0, you'll receive no banner and it will act like an regular old Jenkins install

Answer (score 1):

mostly jenkins will show you the path for initialAdminPassword if you dont find it there, then you have to check jenkins logs

in log you will see

05-May-2017 01:01:41.854 INFO [Jenkins initialization thread] jenkins.install.SetupWizard.init

---

---

---

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

7c249e4ed93c4596972f57e55f7ff32e

This may also be found at: /opt/tomcat/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

---

---

---

Answer (score 1):

Use a lil shortcut to get to the folder:

***cmd + shift + g***

then insert ***/Users/Shared/Jenkins***

there u can see the secrets folder - probably shows that it's locked.

to unlock it: right click on the folder and click info + click on the lock at the bottom. now u can change the rights shown at the bottom of the window

hope that helped :)

Greetings, Stefanie ^__^

Answer (score 1):

If unable to find Jenkins password in the location `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword`

by installing Jenkins generic war on Tomcat server, try below

Solution:
Set environmental variable `JENKINS_HOME` to your jenkins path say

```
JENKINS_HOME ="C:/users/username/apachetomcat/webapps/jenkins"
```

Place `Jenkins.war` in the webapp folder of Tomcat and start Tomcat, 
initial admin password gets generated in the path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to bypass the unlock screen is to copy the UpgradeWizard state to the InstallUtil last execution version, add an install.runSetupWizard file with the contents 'false', and update the config.xml installStateName from NEW to RUNNING.

```
docker exec -it jenkins bash
sed -i s/NEW/RUNNING/ /var/jenkins_home/config.xml
echo 'false' > /var/jenkins_home/jenkins.install.runSetupWizard
cp /var/jenkins_home/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state /var/jenkins_home/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
exit
docker restart jenkins
```

For reference, this is the command I use to run jenkins:

```
docker run --rm --name jenkins --network host -u root -d -v jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkinsci/blueocean:1.16.0
```

You will also want to update the config with the Root URL:

```
echo "<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?><jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration><jenkinsUrl>http://<IP>:8080/</jenkinsUrl></jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration>" > jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml
exit
docker restart jenkins
```

Answer (score 1):

**In case, if you installed/upgraded new versions of jenkins and unable to find admin credentials on server then, ...**

if you are using old version of jenkins and on the top of it you are trying to reinstall/upgrade new version of jenkins then,

the files under "JENKINS_HOME", namely -

1. ${JENKINS_HOME}/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
2. ${JENKINS_HOME}/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state

will cause jenkins to skip the unlock (or admin credentials screen) and webpage directly ask you for username and password. even on server you will not able to find "${JENKINS_HOME}/secrets/initialAdminPassword".

In such case, don't get panic. just try to use old admin user creds in newly installed/upgraded jenkins server.

In simple language, if you have admin creds as admin/admin in old version of jenkins server then, after upgrading jenkins server, the new server won't ask you set password for admin user again. in fact it will use old creds only.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me to skip the initial setup page.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem for docker container in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver) - Ubuntu Releases

1- connect to your docker server or ubuntu server witch ssh or other method

2- run sudo docker ps

3- copy the container name parameter ("NAMES")

4- run sudo docker logs "your_parameters_NAMES_VALUES"

5- Find the folowing sentence "**Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:**" and copy the password

Answer (score 1):

I have found the password in `C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.err`. Open `jenkins.err` text file and scroll down, and you will find the password.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets

then with notepad ++ open file initail Admin Password and paste its content.

thats it

Answer (score 0):

-->if you are using linux machine, then login as **root** user: `sudo su`

-->then go to the below path: `cd /var/lib/jenkins/secrets`

-->just view the IntialAdminPassword file ,you can see the secret key.

-->paste the secret key into jenkins window,it will be unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35981

Try this %2Fjenkins%2F instead of %2Fjenkins in the browser

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal on your mac and open new window (command+T)
2. Paste sudo cat /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
3. It will ask for password, type your password(i gave my mac password, i haven't check if any other password would work) and enter
4. A key would be generated.
5. Copy the key and paste it where it asks you to enter admin password
6. click continue

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be fixed in latest version: mine is 2.4. The error comes because of %2fjenkins%2f in URL. The previous version was coming with %2fjenkins and the same error used to come. They have resolved the issue, but the URL has been changed from %2fjenkins to %2fjenkins%. So as a summary in the URL currently %2fjenkins% is coming. before passing the admin password change it to %2fjenkins. Along with that add a .last_exec_version empty file.

Answer (score 0):

If someone chooses running Jenkins as a **Docker** container, may face the same problem with me.
Because [accessing-the-jenkins-blue-ocean-docker-container](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#accessing-the-jenkins-blue-ocean-docker-container) is quite different,
Common problem is `/var/lib/jenkins/secrets: No such file or directory`
You need to access through `Docker`, the link `Jenkins` provide is quite helpful.
Except `<docker-container-name>` maybe not specified, then you may need to use the container ID.

After

`docker exec -it jenkins-blueocean bash`

or

`docker exec -it YOUR_JENKINS_CONTAINER_ID bash`

The `/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword` would be accessible.

The password would be there.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup Jenkins using Brew, But when I restarted Mac Jenkins was asking for **initialAdminPassword**(The screenshot attached in question)

And the problem was it was not generated under ***sercret*** directory.

So I'd found the Jenkins process which was running on port: **8080** using: `$ sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP` and killed it using `$ sudo kill 66`(66 was process id).

Then I downloaded the latest jenkins **.war** file from: https://jenkins.io/download/

And executed command: `$ java -jar jenkins.war` (Make sure you are in jenkins.war directory).

And that's it everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

**This works well when you are stuck with Docker on Windows and are using Git-Bash**

Presuming something like:

```
# docker run --detach --publish 8080:8080 --volume jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Execute to get the Container ID, for example "d56686cb700d"

```
# docker ps -l
```

Now tell Docker to return the password written in the logs for that Container ID:

```
# docker logs d56686cb700d 2>&1 | grep -A5 -B5 Admin
```

- 2>&1 redirects stderr to stdout
- -A5 includes 5 lines AFTER the line with "Admin" in it
- -B5 includes 5 lines BEFORE the line with "Admin" in it

Output example:

```
Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

47647383733f4387a0d53c873334b707

This may also be found at: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it under below directory. Full issue detail https://github.com/jenkinsci/ibm-security-appscansource-scanner-plugin/issues/2

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins`

Answer (score 0):

Open `jenkins.err` file in `C:\Program Files\Jenkins\`.
In that file check for a hash key after this line

```js
Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:
```

And paste it there in the jenkins prompt. Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

After I apply the secret I get Problem accessing /Jenkins. Reason not found. Below it says powerd by Jetty.

I did these steps to install. 
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins

then this
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins