# Jenkins - cannot log in after a fresh install

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Installed Jenkins 2.39 on Debian as per http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/. Opened it in browser (Firefox) and it's asking for credentials from the log file; copied and pasted that password but it doesn't work. Disabled useSecurity (and friends) in /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml, restarted Jenkins but to no avail: it still asks for password *and* it overwrites all changes to config.xml. The config.xml is clobbered even when chown'd to root and set to read-only (444) access.
Any ideas how to get out of that hole?

UPDATE: apparently an obscure file has to be created in JENKINS_HOME directory with the contents 2 as described at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960883/how-to-unlock-jenkins). User friendliness at its peak.

Comment: `Any ideas` - does your username contain letters in uppercase?

Comment: Are you having a look to the relevant Jenkins home folder? Did you set a JENKINS_HOME environment variable?

Comment: @BrunoLavit the default for JENKINS_HOME is supposed to be `/var/lib/jenkins` which seems to work fine because file time stamps get updated there after a restart. Manually setting this variable in `/etc/init.d/jenkins` didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Gluttton guess you are referring to Jenkins username which would be configurable **after** a successful login? The service itself runs under `jenkins` account.