# How to unlock jenkins on windows 10

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I installed jenkins on my window 10 machine by using the msi I downloaded. It installed fine and has now launched the browser prompting me to unlock jenkins with the initialadminpassword. I can't find this file anywhere. I looked in the install directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins and I have checked the log files and no password was written to it. I even did a search on my whole C: for initialadminpassword and nothing came up. I do have a file called secret.key in my Jenkins install directory but the key in this file isn't working. Any ideas on how I can get around this would be very helpful

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "Unlock Jenkins"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960883/how-to-unlock-jenkins)

Answer (score 7):

In the Jenkins Home directory there should be a `secrets` subfolder. In that directory there should be a file called `initialAdminPassword` (no extension).

This file contains the password it is referring to.

Answer (score 3):

I found the long password in this path C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jinkins.err, in the jinkins.err file all the logs are recorded, so if you screw down slowly you can find the password being generated by the system.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to "[How to “Unlock Jenkins”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35960883/6309)", I use a groovy script in order to make sure an admin account was created.

That means:

- I copy the groovy script in `<Jenkins>/ref/init.groovy.d/security.groovy`
- I launch jenkins.war with `-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false`

In that script, replace the path of the files with the username/password by a Windows path one:

```
def user = new File("/run/secrets/jenkins-adm-name").text.trim()
def pass = new File("/run/secrets/jenkins-adm-pass").text.trim()
```

That way:

- no wizard
- one admin account with a username/password of my choosing.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same issue in windows 10, following the below steps, it's working fine.

0. Unlock Jenkins

[image: unlock jenkins]

1. Open Command Prompt Run as Administrator

[image]

2. Check and Go Junking Installed Location in Command Prompt

[image]

3. Opens the jenkins.err.log file

[image]

4. Find the password

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins do this because it want to ensure Jenkins is securely set up by the administrator ,
So you cannot open this file direct you must going step by step to the path it given to you . 
C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword

1. Go to : C:\WINDOWS\ .
2. Go to : system32
3. .......
4. .......

> Continue tracking path

And you will found it .

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt with admin privilege (i.e, "Run as Admin"). And then navigate to the folder as mentioned in the Jenkins localhost web page. And then run the following command:
notepad initialadminpassword

this will display the password and then you can copy-paste it.

Answer (score 0):

**if you use visual studio code**

**Go to container**

**Files -> var -> jenkins_home -> secrets -> initialadminpassword**