# Jenkins installation path not found in Windows Server 2019

Tags: jenkins, windows-server-2019

I am trying to install Jenkins in Windows Server 2019. Once installed I am asked for `initialadminpassword` under the path `C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword`. But there is no such folder `Jenkins.jenkins` created. The error log of the Jenkins is

```
2020-08-21 10:34:48.910+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2020-08-21 10:35:10.028+0000 [id=1] WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2020-08-21 10:35:10.121+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.30.v20200611; built: 2020-06-11T12:34:51.929Z; git: 271836e4c1f4612f12b7bb13ef5a92a927634b0d; jvm 1.8.0_261-b12
2020-08-21 10:35:11.074+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2020-08-21 10:35:11.134+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-08-21 10:35:11.134+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-08-21 10:35:11.142+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2020-08-21 10:35:12.073+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2020-08-21 10:35:12.230+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@aadd0{Jenkins v2.235.5,/,file:///C:/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Jenkinswar/,AVAILABLE}{C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkinswar}
2020-08-21 10:35:12.261+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@ecb5b8{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-08-21 10:35:12.261+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @24253ms
2020-08-21 10:35:12.261+0000 [id=19]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
2020-08-21 10:35:15.751+0000 [id=26]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2020-08-21 10:35:15.785+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2020-08-21 10:35:18.229+0000 [id=24]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
2020-08-21 10:35:18.231+0000 [id=24]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins
2020-08-21 10:35:18.291+0000 [id=26]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions
2020-08-21 10:35:22.407+0000 [id=25]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config loaded
2020-08-21 10:35:22.407+0000 [id=25]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config adapted
2020-08-21 10:35:22.407+0000 [id=25]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Loaded all jobs
2020-08-21 10:35:22.409+0000 [id=25]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Configuration for all jobs updated
2020-08-21 10:35:22.490+0000 [id=40]    INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Started Download metadata
2020-08-21 10:35:22.520+0000 [id=40]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Attempt #1 to do the action check updates server
2020-08-21 10:35:24.226+0000 [id=26]    INFO    o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext#prepareRefresh: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@2fedd9: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Aug 21 10:35:24 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-08-21 10:35:24.226+0000 [id=26]    INFO    o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext#obtainFreshBeanFactory: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@2fedd9]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a9b333
2020-08-21 10:35:24.256+0000 [id=26]    INFO    o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory#preInstantiateSingletons: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a9b333: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
2020-08-21 10:35:24.987+0000 [id=26]    INFO    o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext#prepareRefresh: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@4189c8: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Aug 21 10:35:24 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-08-21 10:35:24.987+0000 [id=26]    INFO    o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext#obtainFreshBeanFactory: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@4189c8]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19d0844
2020-08-21 10:35:24.987+0000 [id=26]    INFO    o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory#preInstantiateSingletons: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19d0844: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
2020-08-21 10:35:25.618+0000 [id=26]    INFO    jenkins.install.SetupWizard#init: 

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

***password here***

This may also be found at: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

2020-08-21 10:35:47.307+0000 [id=40]    INFO    h.m.DownloadService$Downloadable#load: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller
2020-08-21 10:35:47.307+0000 [id=40]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Performed the action check updates server successfully at the attempt #1
2020-08-21 10:35:47.317+0000 [id=40]    INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Finished Download metadata. 24,827 ms
2020-08-21 10:35:48.605+0000 [id=26]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2020-08-21 10:35:48.636+0000 [id=18]    INFO    hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

And the Jenkins Wrapper Log is

```
2020-08-21 10:34:47,776 INFO  - Starting C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\\bin\java.exe -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkinswar"
2020-08-21 10:34:47,783 INFO  - Extension loaded: killOnStartup
2020-08-21 10:34:47,798 WARN  - The requested PID file 'C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkinsjenkins.pid' does not exist. The runaway process won't be checked
2020-08-21 10:34:47,925 INFO  - Started process 5568
2020-08-21 10:34:47,935 DEBUG - Forwarding logs of the process System.Diagnostics.Process (java) to winsw.SizeBasedRollingLogAppender
2020-08-21 10:34:47,954 INFO  - Recording PID of the started process:5568. PID file destination is C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkinsjenkins.pid
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are running a x64 system. Maybe you find the file in the SysWOW64 folder:
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword`

Comment: My environment variable in Jenkins was pointing to another completely (inexistent) different path, but I was able to found It here. I still don't know why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If password not open ,please refer the link

[How to unlock jenkins on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559565/how-to-unlock-jenkins-on-windows-10)

Open Command prompt with admin and Go to secrets folder  and Type more initial*
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\secrets>more initial*

This is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the path being referred to in the question

Wrong path: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword`

Correct path: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword`

There is a \ missing between Jenkins and .jenkins. Otherwise it will show the initialAdminPassword like it usually does.