# An error occurred during installation: No such plugin: cloudbees-folder

Tags: jenkins-plugins, tomcat8.5

An error occurred during installation: No such plugin: cloudbees-folder (While installing Jenkins suggested plugins getting the error on windows 10)

Comment: always look for official images mentioned here
https://www.jenkins.io/download/

Answer (score 12):

This work for me:
http://localhost:8080/restart

OR
`service jenkins restart` on my Ubuntu

Comment: I tried that, but got this message: `Jenkins can't restart itself under the current configuration`.

Comment: can you share your working environment docker/ubuntu/windows/mac ?

Comment: Windows. I figured out how to fix the issue for me though (see my answer above)

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users, restarting the Jenkins service will resolve the issue.

For that Open `Task Manager (Ctrl+Sft+Esc) -> Services -> right-click on Jenkins` service and choose the option restart

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Jenkin's image in Docker if you see this error just try to execute the below command:
http://localhost:8080/safeRestart
you will get a prompt do you need to restart don't click on yes just ignore then start creating your jobs by clicking on NEW, it's just a plugin

Answer (score 2):

As a comment suggested: always look for official images mentioned here [jenkins.io/download](https://www.jenkins.io/download/).

I faced the same issue when using the docker image `jenkins:2.60.3`, it turned out that this image isn't an official one, the official images look like `jenkins/jenkins:<something>`, you can find them here: https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins

Answer (score 1):

For the docker version

1-open the browser

2- write your_ip_address:your_docker_port/restart

Note: you must have the password generated by your Jenkins server
if you do have [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960883/how-to-unlock-jenkins/68500866#68500866)

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a firewall (local or through a VPN), there's a good chance that it's failing to download files correctly.

Try installing from another location or disabling the VPN.
Or request your network admin to allow the connections.

When I initially started my server while on a VPN there were two connection failure stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Jenkins on Ubuntu in AWS.

I had this initial problem after booting up the box.

Ran the following:

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

All working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Context Path** in tomcat for Jenkins that you have given during deployment and then restart/safeRestart from that path.

**For example:** The Path in the below screenshot is "/jenkins", So the restart URL will be

http://localhost:8080/jenkins/restart **OR**
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/safeRestart

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I used a jenkins:2.60.3 Docker image, and it was solved when I use the jenkins/jenkins Docker image, so delete the current image and try this image:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name jenkinsContainer jenkins/jenkins
```

Answer (score -1):

I just Unchecked all the plugins and clicked on the install button. After that, it successfully takes me to the inside.

Answer (score -3):

Just restart the machine. It successfully worked for me.